# Error : Invalid Token, when fetching value of node from XML

Tags: c#, .net

In the below code, i need to get the values of nodes inside my root node

```
Root Node :   <basemap:AlterationService xmlns:basemap="http://www.xxx.com/basemap">
```

for which i need to provide node name to XmlNodeList, inorder to fetch data.
i am using the below c# code to fetch the value but, i am getting the error as,

```
'<basemap:AlterationService xmlns:basemap="http://www.xxx.com/basemap"' has an invalid token.
```

C# :

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load("C:/Test/Sample.xml");

    string RootNode = "basemap:AlterationService xmlns:basemap=\"http://www.xxx.com/basemap\"";
     XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes(RootNode); //Error in this line
     foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
     {
        ................
        ................
     }


XML : 

   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <basemap:AlterationService xmlns:basemap="http://www.xxx.com/basemap">
      .....
      .....
   </basemap:AlterationService>
```

Comment: shouldn't you use "basemap:AlterationService" instead of "basemap:AlterationService xmlns:basemap=\"http://www.xxx.com/basemap\""???

Comment: @AdilMammadov If i use as you said, i am getting the error : Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.